# How do I insert a document along with the result of a find query together in a collection in a single query in MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, non-relational-database

Suppose I have a collection named *oldCollection* which has a record like

```
{
name: "XYZ"
}
```

Now I want to insert this data into a new collection named *newCollection*. But I also want to add another key-value field (suppose a boolean field **exists**) for this same record like :

```
{
name: XYZ
exists:true
}
```

I am using find query to extract the required data and insert it into the new collection but how can I add more fields (like exists in the above example) in the same record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $out aggregation stage:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
  "$addFields": { "exists": true }
},
{
  "$out": "resultedCollection"
}
])
```

see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MpAhpVp7GeI)

Comment: I am getting an error- BSONError: cyclic dependency detected,  when I am running this on my local.


This is the query that I am writing:

db.newCollection.aggregate([ { "$addFields": { "exists": true } }, { "$out": db.oldCollection.find({},{name:1, _id:0}) }])

Comment: $out doesn't support random query in arguments, it requires specified `collection` or `db` + `collection`. See https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#syntax

Comment: How should I proceed then?
Can you suggest me something please?

Comment: your question above doesn't make sense. The answer I provided corresponds to what you requested initially, Idk what's your question now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72554434/migrating-data-from-old-collection-to-new-collecton-in-mongodb

This is my query. Can you please have a look at it.

Comment: the answer above with aggregate + $addFields + $out is exactly what you're looking for